# Regex code for any string containing BOTH letters AND digits and possibly underscores and dashes

Tags: regex, ms-word

My regex knowledge is pretty limited, but I'm trying to write/find an expression that will capture the following string types in a document:

DO match:

- ADY123
- AD12ADY
- 1HGER_2
- 145-DE-FR2
- Bicycle1
- 2Bicycle
- 128D
- 128878P

DON'T match:

- BICYCLE
- 183-329-193
- 3123123

Is such an expression possible? Basically, it should find any string containing letters AND digits, regardless of whether the string contains a dash or underscore. I can find the first two using the following two regex:

- /([A-Z][0-9])\w+/g
- /([0-9][A-Z)\w+/g

But searching for possible dashes and hyphens makes it more complicated...

Thanks for any help you can provide! :)

MORE INFO:

I've made slight progress with: ([A-Z|a-z][0-9]+-*_*\w+) but it doesn't capture strings with more than one hyphen.

I had a document with a lot of text strings and number strings, which I don't want to capture. What I do want is any product code, which could be any length string with or without hyphens and underscores but will always include at least one digit and at least one letter.

Comment: What do these examples look like in the larger context of all your data? Could you give an example of something you don't want to capture?

Comment: Certainly, I've tried to give a little more info.

Comment: @user3842077: "Could you give an example of something you don't want to capture?" — You have't added any examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following expression with the case-insensitive mode:

```
\b((?:[a-z]+\S*\d+|\d\S*[a-z]+)[a-z\d_-]*)\b
```

Explanation:

```
\b                   # Assert position at a word boundary
(                    # Beginning of capturing group 1
  (?:                # Beginning of the non-capturing group
    [a-z]+\S*\d+     # Match letters followed by numbers
    |                # OR
    \d+\S*[a-z]+     # Match numbers followed by letters
  )                  # End of the group
  [a-z\d_-]*         # Match letter, digit, '_', or '-' 0 or more times
)                    # End of capturing group 1
\b                   # Assert position at a word boundary
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wO6xT3/5)

Comment: Thanks, but that also captures words and numbers, I want only strings that aren't all letters and all digits.

Comment: @user3842077: Just so we're clear: can you update your question to include some examples of strings that you *don't* want matched?

Comment: I've updated it accordingly - sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @user3842077: Oops, sorry! I'd forgotten to update the demo link. It's been updated. Check now.

Comment: @user3842077: Of course, if you want to capture the data, you can just put the entire expression in a pair of parentheses like so: `((?:[a-z]+.*?\d+|\d+.*?[a-z]+)[a-z\d_-]+)`. See demo: http://regex101.com/r/wO6xT3/2

Comment: Thanks, Amal... and sorry to be a pain, but could you edit it slightly to capture strings with a single letter, too? Such as 128D and 128878P? I hope it's not too much trouble - the rest is perfect!

Comment: @user3842077: Then you can just change the `+` (which means "*one or more* times") at the end to `*` (which means "*zero or more* times"). The full regex: `((?:[a-z]+.*?\d+|\d+.*?[a-z]+)[a-z\d_-]*)`. I've edited the answer to reflect this (and made some other minor improvements, too).

Comment: It looks easy but these kinds of specs often give rise to convoluted patterns, +1 :)