# Regex code for product models and codes

Tags: regex, vba

I found a very useful regex code in order to extract product codes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765181/regex-code-for-any-string-containing-both-letters-and-digits-and-possibly-unders), this is the expression:

```
\b((?:[a-z]+\S*\d+|\d\S*[a-z]+)[a-z\d_-]*)\b
```

It works almost perfectly, but  I need to detect and extract only the product codes that have a length of at least 5 digits.

```
For example, for the following strings:

5T COFFEE BREW FOR BLACK & DECKER DCM-601B
10T COFFEE BREW FOR BLACK & DECKER DCM-1100B
10T COFFEE BREW FOR BLACK & DECKER DCM-1100W
8T COFFEE BREW FOR BLACK & DECKER CM-1509
Rice Cookers 15T DOMESTIC USE RC5428, ELECTRIC BLACK & DECKER
Rice Cookers 15T RC/5723 DOMESTIC USE, ELECTRIC BLACK & DECKER
Rice Cookers B D REF.RC3203
Hand mixer, S / M, PS62509R
SLOW COOKING POTS, HAMILTON BEACH, HB33136T
OVEN 110V TOSTA SANKEY REF.TO-9
24 PZA METAL TEAPOT S / M CHINA REF: 92479
ELECTRIC RICE COOKER, 1.5 L ROYAL ROA-15SV
ELECTRIC RICE COOKER, 1.8 L ROYAL ROA-18SV
ELECTRIC RICE COOKER, 2.2 L ROYAL ROA-22SV
ELECTRIC RICE COOKER, 2.8 L ROYAL ROA-28SV
Waffle Makers DOMESTIC USE, ELECTRIC BLACK & DECKER G-49TD
2.00 PZA TOAST OVEN, METAL / GLASS ROYAL, CHINA, REF: RTH-28A
20.00 PZA RICE, METAL, BLACK & DECKER, CHINA, REF: RCB550S

I get:

5TDCM-601B
10TDCM-1100B
10TDCM-1100W
8TCM-1509
15TRC5428
15TRC/5723
REF.RC3203
PS62509R
HB33136T
REF.TO-9
92479
ROA-15SV
ROA-18SV
ROA-22SV
ROA-28SV
G-49TD
2.00RTH-28A
20.00RCB550S

Desired outcome:

DCM-601B
DCM-1100B
DCM-1100W
CM-1509
RC5428
RC/5723
REF.RC3203
PS62509R
HB33136T
REF.TO-9
92479
ROA-15SV
ROA-18SV
ROA-22SV
ROA-28SV
G-49TD
RTH-28A
RCB550S
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why not split the line by space and get the last element?

Comment: Just get the index of the last space and use the `Mid` function.

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume that your codes contain 5 or more non-whitespace symbols, and there must be at least 1 digit, the regex for the codes will be:

```
\b(?!\d+\.\d+)(?=\S*\d)\S{5,}\b
```

See [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/uW6iF5/11)

The `(?!\d+\.\d+)` disallows float/decimal numbers like `1.2345` or `12.44`.

Comment: The strings that I want to extract are not necessarily at the end

Comment: Are you sure the codes can have 3 or 4 digits? Maybe 5 and more? Have a look at [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/uW6iF5/1).

Comment: Almost perfect @stribizhev but also I want to extract those cases that the code contains only numbers, I updated with this case: 24 PZA METAL TEAPOT S / M CHINA REF: 92479

Comment: Both work, but first one is better, thaks a lot @stribizhev

Comment: I updated with 2 more cases, because I recently found them in other strings, could you help me?

Comment: Updated, please check.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I understood your question, but you can use a regex like this to get the product codes you want:

```
((?:\w{2,}\.)?\w{1,}[.\/-]?\d+\w+)(?=\b)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/dQ2qI4/5)**

[image]

Comment: Because strings that I want to extract, do not necessarily contain a hyphen, they could contain any character as "/" or "_" for example.

Comment: @Israel btw, if you want to allow codes like `99999` then you can use this sample https://regex101.com/r/dQ2qI4/4

Comment: It works but fails for the last 4 cases that I recently add, using my original regex It detect them but not with yours.

Comment: Almost perfect, I added just one more case @Fede : Waffle Makers DOMESTIC USE, ELECTRIC BLACK & DECKER G-49TD

Comment: @Israel fixed here https://regex101.com/r/dQ2qI4/6. Btw, bear in mind that your original question was changed 6 times, this is changing the scope of your question and deprecating user's answers.

Comment: Thanks, It works perfect @Fede, sorry but in my original data I have a lot of cases, I show just a little part, please update your answer to give it a check mark.

Comment: @Israel glad to help. Updated now.